# Non isomorphic affine varieties with homeomorphic spectra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading around trying to get a feel for what algebraic geometry is about and I've come across this question which, if true, would make some aspects of how the subject is presented more understandable for me.

As the title of the post suggests, my question is simply this: Are there non-isomorphic affine varieties $X$, $Y$ (over $\mathbb{C}$) for which $Spec(R(X))$ and $Spec(R(Y))$ are homeomorphic? Equivalently, are there non-isomorphic finitely generated reduced $\mathbb{C}$-algebras with homeomorphic spectra?

From Vakil Exercice 3.2.R I know that when a ring $R$ is allowed to have nilpotent elements then $Spec(R/\sqrt{(0)})$ and $Spec(R)$ will be homeomorphic but are there examples of this phenomenon in the realm of classical (i.e. non properly scheme theoretic) algebraic geometry?

Comment: Irreducible curves over the complex numbers have all the same cardinal and their topology is, in each case, the cofinite one. The corresponding schemes have one extra point.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! This is a good question with some solid context. As Mariano suggests, all irreducible curves over a field are homeomorphic, and the linked duplicate provides a proof.

Comment: @KReiser the "dup" is about classical varieties while this one is about affine schemes